# where to find Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I'm opening a 2005 SSIS pakage and also an old C# project..both are in this solution here.  I'm missing namespaces and I can't find the assemblies to add back to my references folder for my C# Project

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline

for example is not one I find in the list of references in the .NET references tab.  So how the hell do I get these SQL Server assemblies?  Do I have to install the SQL Server 2008 sdk?

Lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing SQL Server 2008R2 feature "Client Tools SDK", you can find it at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's 2005, you'll need

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll`

or

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll`

If that's not available on the current machine, you will need to acquire your SQL Server 2005 installation media. I cannot recall what the minimum feature set you'd need to select to ensure those DLLs get installed.

Comment: not for 2008, I need to use the 100 folder actually but thanks.  I figured this out later after this post.

Comment: Ah, I see the discrepancy. In your initial paragraph you reference 2005 but the latter you indicate you wanted 2008.